# Why doesn't rails clear (a cached) belongs_to value when setting the _id value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails, consider:

```
> p = Post.new
> p.author = Person.find(1)
> p.author_id = 99
> p.author_id
 => 99
> p.author
 => #<Person id:1, name: "Person 1">
```

What I've never understood: is there a conscious decision cq some reasoning behind not clearing the +author+ value after the +author_id+ is set?  Is there a plugin of some sorts that fixes this?

Comment: My personal guess is that getting to `author` from `author_id` would require a database lookup, which may not be what the programmer wants. If you save the record, it should update the `author`.

Comment: If I did:

    > p = Post.new
    > p.author_id = 99
    > p.author

Then it would require a database lookup as well. I don't see the difference. Why leave things in an inconsistent state?

Comment: I don't understand why you would even do that. Choose one way or the other to update the post's author. Save and reload `p` to get everything in a consistent state if you have to do the above for some reason.